# I can't figure out how to get hard hat working in VSCode

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I installed version 8.3.0 of hardhat vis the terminal, but when I type npx hardhat to create a new file, it just brings up a list of global and available options. Additionally, hardhat has not created any files in my editors tab in VS Code. Help?

Comment: Can you post the result of the command?

Comment: you are supposed to choose which type of project you want to create from the list and then it will create all files